# motor run protection

Tags: electrical

I would like to run my swimming pool pump (220 v single phase AC) on solar panels, I plan to use a inverter to get 220 V.  I plan to run the pump continuously during the time the panels produce enough watts to run the motor. How do I control the startup and switch off during times when the panels do not produce enough watts, say early in the morning and late in the afternoon etc.?

Comment: Does your inverter have an "under-voltage lock-out" feature?

Comment: Have you sized the solar panels? A 1hp pool pump could draw close to 2kW, which could require 13 square meters (140 square feet) of roof area. With that big an investment, you probably want it to be multi-purpose, rather than dedicated to the pool pump.

Comment: Starting currents for a 1 Hp pump 240v (common called 220) will be a minimum of 2kw with normal peak draws for a short period being closer to 4-8KW. If the available current is not available the system may "brown out" drawing more current for longer times causing motor overheating and possibly inverter damage. Full load amperage for a 1 hp motor is 8 amps a 3 HP 17 amps. As I said normal starting current is usually 2-4 times the full load amperage.